# Creating Mosaic Dataset in ArcMap with Colormap as renderer or adding Colormap after creation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, mosaic-dataset, colormap

I have several rasters in tiff format that have a colormap assigned to them:

[image]

I then create a Mosaic Dataset with specs matching the imagery and add all of my tiffs to it (you can ignore the warnings this is just to illustrate what i did):

[image]

Colormap does not show up and it does not let me import my Colormap from the tiffs:

[image]

Is there any way to add/import my Colormaps so that we can view the data according to those values?

Comment: Don't know if what I'm suggesting is a red herring or even possible but may be you could apply a [colormap raster function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/colormap-function.htm) to the mosaic dataset?

Comment: Turns out you can apply a colormap to a mosaic dataset through the colormap raster function, be aware it will create a new layer.

Comment: hmm yes i think you are right but i think this just creates a new raster that would need to be added to a mosaic dataset and would then lose it's color map... all of the raster referenced in my mosaic dataset have a color map assigned to them but i cannot display the mosaic dataset using that colormap.

Comment: Can you "borrow" symbology from that new raster?

Comment: no or else i would just borrow from the existing rasters that are referenced in the mosaic. but if i do that it throws some error about colormaps aren't in the dataset blah blah. it is kind of some chicken and egg stuff.

Comment: If you save a raster function as an xml then you can apply this function in your mosaic and it will use your colormap inside the mosaic, not in another layer. I don't know if this is what you want but If it is I can explain it better.

Comment: @Albert yes please explain better. keep in mind i am using a mosaic dataset which is just a pointer to a set of tiffs

Comment: It seems that you had discrete colors in your initial raster - why are you using streched symbology?

Comment: I wasn't actually using stretched this is just an example of what I am seeing. I don't want discreet colors I want color map as it is set colors that mean set things

Comment: @Hornbydd, I think your comment is the answer.

Comment: I try to put the colormap function on the mosaic dataset(canopy height mosaic), however I got the below error message. Is anyone has idea what is the cause
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw7Ou.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw7Ou.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163836)

Answer (score 5):

You can **apply a colormap to a mosaic** using this workflow. Keep in mind that your data needs to be integer type.

First, you need to create and export a colormap from your styled raster.

[image]

Then you apply this colormap as a **raster function**, load your .clr file. This will create a new layer.

[image]

In the symbology tab of this new layer, export as a raster function template. It will create a file.rft.xml

[image]

The last step is to apply this function in your mosaic by using the [Edit Raster Function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/edit-raster-function.htm) tool.

[image]

It is not very intuitive but it can be done, you may need to calculate statistics of the mosaic but you can do it as an option when you add your rasters to the mosaic.

[image]

Comment: this is where i made it. the colormap colors are displayed but it is using rgb in the table of contents. i am wondering if there is a way to have it show the colormap values there. you are showing the colors the same as the color map but the renderer is still rgb if you check test1-->Image-->Symbology there is still no option for Colormap

Comment: Maybe there is another approach but afaik, I think you can either have it in another layer with the full legend or inside the mosaic as an RGB.